# Unbanning a member from all guilds the bot is in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to unban a member from all guilds that the bot is in.
My issue is when i run the command with the banned users ID in it i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 375, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 132, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10007): Unknown Member
```

These are the steps I have tried.

```
            async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
                userr = await guild.fetch_member(id)
                if userr in guild.bans:
                    await guild.unban(userr)
                    await ctx.send("Unbanned the user.")
```

I am expecting the bot to unban the specified ID from all the servers the bot is in.

FULL CODE:

```
    @commands.slash_command(name="unban", description="When you have specified the user name and hashtag the bot will unban that user from all servers.")
    async def unban(self, ctx, id: discord.SlashCommandOptionType.string):
        async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
            try:
                user = await guild.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)
            except discord.NotFound:
                continue
        
        head_admin = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Head Admin")
        developer = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Developer")
        owner = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Owner")
        if head_admin or developer or owner in user.roles:
            async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
                userr = await guild.fetch_member(id)
                if userr in guild.bans:
                    await guild.unban(userr)
                    await ctx.send("Unbanned the user.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some troubleshooting messing around with different user converters I have found the solution to my problem.

I had changed the user_id input to a user input which then you would put the user ID in.
It then loops through the guilds and unbans the user from all guilds.
If the user is not detected in a guilds ban list it will continue going through them.

```
    @commands.slash_command(name="unban", description="When you have specified the user name and hashtag the bot will unban that user from all servers.")
    async def unban(self, ctx, userr: discord.User):
        async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
            try:
                user = await guild.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)
            except discord.NotFound:
                continue
        
            head_admin = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Head Admin")
            developer = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Developer")
            owner = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Owner")
            if head_admin or developer or owner in user.roles:
                try:
                    async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
                        await guild.unban(userr)
                except:
                    continue
                await ctx.send("Unbanned the user.")
            else:
                await ctx.respond("You don't have permission to run this command.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this is because your `id` parameter is a string and it should be an int. Or you should be casting it to an int. Additionally, I think naming it `id` is bad practice as it will conflict with a builtin.

```py
@commands.slash_command(name="unban", description="When you have specified the user name and hashtag the bot will unban that user from all servers.")
async def unban(self, ctx, user_id):

    try:
        user_id = int(user_id)
    except ValueError:
        # not an actual int
        # send message here
        return

    async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
        try:
            user = await guild.fetch_member(ctx.author.id)
        except discord.NotFound:
            continue
        
        head_admin = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Head Admin")
        developer = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Developer")
        owner = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Owner")
        if head_admin or developer or owner in user.roles:
            async for guild in self.bot.fetch_guilds():
                userr = await guild.fetch_member(user_id)
                if userr in guild.bans:
                    await guild.unban(userr)
                    await ctx.send("Unbanned the user.")
```

Then just use the `user_id` as the parameter instead. You can get that by right-clicking on a user with the developer settings turned on.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I am attempting the enter the discord ID but discord is telling me that it is an invalid integer. See the screenshot for what im saying.
https://prnt.sc/HPxAscCHKl34

Comment: Adding to what ESloman said, the parameter user_id option can be changed to a discord.Option type. This can be used to make the command cleaner, and to get a selector for users.

Comment: Modified my answer to take a string and convert it to an int for you.

Comment: @BlueRobin, I consdired making it a user option, but as it's to do with `unbanning` I'm not sure the user would be in the guild and therefore not actually selectable as a user.

Comment: Hey i am still receiving the unknown member error. The error seems to be pointing at line 128 which is. `userr = await guild.fetch_member(user_id)`.

Comment: Yeah you'd get that if the user isn't in that particular guild. You can add a try/except with `try/except discord.NotFound` and continue like we do earlier on in the function.